# How many elements are in the set $\{(a,b) | a,b~\text{are elements of}~\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}~\text{and}~1 \leq a \leq b \leq 15\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many elements are in the set $\{(a,b) | a,b~\text{are elements of}~\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}~\text{and}~1 \leq a \leq b \leq 15\}$?

I managed to find $4$ elements, $\{1,2,3,4\}$

The way I did this is: 
 $1 \times 1 = 1 \\
 1 \times 2 = 2 \\
 1 \times 3 = 3 \\
 1 \times 4 = 4 \\
 2 \times 2 = 4 \\
 2 \times 3 = 6 \\
 2 \times 4 = 8 \\
 3 \times 3 = 9 \\
 3 \times 4 = 12$

anything after these calculations make the total greater than $15$...

Comment: Are you sure that $a$ and $b$ *are* elements of $\Bbb{N\times N}$ rather than $(a,b)$ is an element of $\Bbb{N\times N}$?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to say that $a\times b $ should be less than 15.  It appears to say that $b$ should be at most 15 and that $a$ should be no bigger than $a$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $1,2,3,4$ are elements in $\Bbb N$, whereas you are asked to count *ordered pairs*.

The question asks how many pairs of natural numbers, $(a,b)$, are there, with $a\leq b$, $1\leq a$ and $b\leq 15$. For example $(1,1)$ is such pair, $(1,2)$ and $(4,15)$ are such pairs also.

You need to find a way to count these pairs.

**HINT:** For each $n$ between $1$ and $15$, how many pairs are there $(a,n)$ such that $1\leq a\leq n$?

Comment: better then mine..+1

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of possibilitis to choose 2 elements from the set 
$$N=\{1,2,...,15\}.$$
This is $\binom{15}{2}+15$.
Here $\binom{15}{2}$ is the number of pairs with $1\leq a<b\leq 15$ and $15$ is the number of pairs with $1\leq a=b\leq 15$.

Other way, for $a=1$ you got $15$ $b$'s. For $a=2$ you have $14$.
So your answer is the sum
$$1+2+3+...+15=\frac{15\cdot 16}{2}=120.$$

Comment: Your work is correct, but you should explain that $\binom{15}{2}$ represents the number of ordered pairs $(a, b)$ such that $1 \leq a < b \leq 15$, while $15$ represents the number of ordered pairs $(a, b)$ such that $1 \leq a = b \leq 15$.

Comment: Thank you, an edit was made.